# Trying to get the duplicate serial numbers repeating more than three times from this list using perl or awk command

Tags: linux, perl, awk

For example: From the below example I was trying to get the duplicated serial numbers which only repeats more than three times.

```
Time     serial no's     oui   product class
23:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:18 G1A117072200565|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
22:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:18 G1A117072200565|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:07:51 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:10:36 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
20:11:51 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

So if I return the output it should be something like this:

Only duplicated serial no's

output should be:

```
G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

(as this serial no's are only repeating more than two times)

Commands I used:

```
sort  sed2file.csv | uniq -id > sortedfile.csv
perl -ne 'print if $a{$_}++' filename
```

Comment: How was the output different to your expectations? What's your question?

Comment: so my question was inspite of the timestamp whatever it may be either same or different i need to fetch only serial numbers repeating more than 3times.

Comment: Is the order of the output relevant?

Answer (score 1):

awk solution:

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 { split($2, cols, "[|]"); serials[cols[1]]++; rows[cols[1]]=$2 }
       END { for (s in serials) if (serials[s] >= 3) print rows[s] }' input.txt
G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

Keeps track of the number of times each serial number appears, and after processing the entire file, prints out just those that show up 3 or more times, discarding the timestamps. Note that this will print the matching records in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tail` plus a perl one-liner like so:

```
tail -n +2 input_file | \
perl -F'/[|]|\s+/' -lane '
print join( q{|}, @F[1..$#F]) if $seen{ $F[1] }++ == 2;'
```

Prints:

```
G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

Here, `tail -n +2` skips the first line (header). It is optional, but I prefer it for robust, clean code and results downstream.

The perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e`: tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n`: loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l`: strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when `print`-ing.
`-a`: split `$_` into array `@F` on regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'/[|]|\s+/'`: when splitting into `@F`, use this regex: pipe (`|`) or one or more whitespaces (`\s+`).

The code keeps the count of times the 2nd field (serial number) is seen. For that, it uses `$seen{ $F[1] }++`. Note that arrays in Perl are 0-indexed.

When the count is equal to 2 (that is, when it is about to become 3 after auto-increment), `print` is executed.

If you want to print the entire line, just use `print` with no arguments, which is the same as `print $_`. Here, however, all columns except the first one (indexes: `1..$#F`) are joined together on `|` and printed.

Comment: So i have tried ur command it prints [root@tacos santosh]# cat t2
23:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:18 G1A117072200565|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
22:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:18 G1A117072200565|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:07:51 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:10:36 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
20:11:51 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
[root@tacos santosh]# tail -n +2 t2 | \
> perl -F'/[|]|\s+/' -lane '
> print join( q{|}, @F[1..$#F]) if $seen{ $F[1] }++ == 2;'
G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4

Comment: what if i have a 100k records with  and i have to print the serial numbers that are repeating more than three times irrespective of time stamp.

Comment: Backslash means the command continues on the next line in shell. If you want it all in 1 line, do this: `tail -n +2 input_file | perl ...`. No ` \ > `

Comment: It should easily work for 100k records. It prints each serial num that occurs 3 or more times. It prints each such number only once.

Comment: hi Timur Shtatland,Your command works exactly fine,Thanks for that.Last question i have is how do i get a list of serial numbers only equal to three ie only repaeating three times.

Comment: was trying to get list of devices that informed more than 20 times per day, and also list of devices that inform more than 100 times per day

Comment: tail -n +2 sed4file.csv | perl -F'/[|]|\s+/' -lane '
print join( q{|}, @F[1..$#F]) if $seen{ $F[1] }++ == 100;' > listgreaterthan100


tail -n +2 sed4file.csv  | perl -F'/[|]|\s+/' -lane '
print join( q{|}, @F[1..$#F]) if $seen{ $F[1] }++ == 20;' > listgreaterthan20.csv

Comment: I used the above command to get the serial numbers list repaeating more than 20 and 100 times but the output seems to be odd

Comment: [root@tacos santosh]# cat listgreaterthan100
D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
000FB3|MI424WR-GEN3I
001404|QIP-7100
880355|G3100
0002DE|CHS335HDC

Comment: @Sanjala Re: "how do i get a list of serial numbers only equal to three ie only repeating three times": I recommend asking a new question, saying you need the lines where serial number is repeated exactly 3 times (??) - not 3 times or more. This allows the current thread to be dedicated to 1 and only 1 question, as is the custom on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code how it can be achieved in perl. See if it fits your purpose.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;                      # debug flag

my %data;                           # data storage
my $num_duplicates = 3;             # treshold for duplicates

for (<DATA>) {                      # walk through data
    next if /Time/;                 # skip header
    chomp;                          # snip \n
    my($time,$serial) = split ' ';  # get time and serial
    $data{$serial}++;               # count duplicates
}

say Dumper(\%data) if $debug;       # look into what we collected

for my $k ( sort keys %data ) {     # look for treshold
    say $k if $data{$k} >= $num_duplicates; 
}

__DATA__
Time     serial no's     oui   product class
23:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:18 G1A117072200565|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
22:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:17 G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:38:18 G1A117072200565|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:07:51 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
23:10:36 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
20:11:51 G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

Output

```
G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it trivially with `awk`, e.g.

```
awk '{seen[$2]++; if(seen[$2]==3) print $2}' serials.txt
```

Output:

```
G1A114071803436|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
G1A114080901301|D4A928|FiOS-Gen4
```

Above you keep the `seen` array indexed by the second field holding the number of times the `serial|oui|product class` is seen. When it equals 3, just output that set of values (it will not print before the count equals 3 and ignore occurrences afterwards due to the `==` used)

Comment: I use this command to get list of values of serial numbers repeating more than 20times but i dont see this command working....I used the command below           awk '{seen[$2]++; if(seen[$2]==20) print $2}' sed4file.csv  > greaterthan20.csv

Comment: Has the format of the lines/records change from your original question? The seen array is indexed by the 2nd field, so if your new lines contain additional whitespace that cause the field numbers to change -- you must adjust the array index. If the format has changed from your question, add an edit to the bottom of your question and I'll take a look. If you run this on the data presented in your question is works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perl command line solution (assuming your data is in a file called data.txt):

```
perl -anE 'BEGIN { <> } \
           END { for (keys %id) { say $_ if $id{$_} > 2 } } \
           $id{$F[1]}++' data.txt
```

I've split the code across three lines (which is, to be honest, a bit big for a command-line program). I hope that makes it easier to follow.

-anE : Command line options. -a Autosplits input into `@F`, -n loops over input a line at a time, -E executes the code that follows.

`BEGIN { <> }` : Block that is executed before starting to read the input file. Simply reads a line from the file (to skip the headers).

`END { ... }` : Block that executed after the input file is all read.

`for (keys %id) { ... }` : Execute this loop for every key in the `%id` hash.

`say $_ if $id{$_} > 2` : If we've seen more than two lines, print the key.

`$id{$F[1]}++` : This is all of the code that is actually executed for each line in the input file. The input record is split on whitespace and stored in `@F`. `$F[1]` is, therefore, the second field in the record (the ID that you're interested in) and we increment the value in the `%id` hash using that ID as a key.

Comment: [root@tacos santosh]# perl -anE 'BEGIN { <> } \
           END { for (keys %id) { say $_ if $id{$_} > 19 } } \
           $id{$F[1]}++' t2
Can't call method "END" without a package or object reference at -e line 2, <> line 2.
[root@tacos santosh]#